# Port 8080 connection refused with Tomcat running on SSL CentOS server

Tags: tomcat, centos

I'm very new to this so likely it's something simple, but I've read other responses to similar questions and tried various solutions with nothing working for me yet.  When I start Tomcat and check port 8080, the connection is refused and the Tomcat success page doesn't show.  Right now I'm just trying to figure out what I need to configure so that Tomcat listens on the correct ports once it's started.

I had to manually add the JAVA_HOME path to .bashrc for the JRE_HOME to be included below.

```
# sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.39
Using CATALINA_HOME:    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.39
Using CATALINA_TEMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.39/temp
Using JRE_HOME:         /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.10.0.9-0.e17_9x86_64
Using CLASSPATH:        /usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.39/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.39/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:
Tomcat started.
```

Afterward, trying to access the website with :8080 at the end times out the connection.

```
# telnet 162.0.226.222 8080
Trying 162.0.226.222...
telnet: connect to address 162.0.226.222: Connection refused
```

The port is still closed after starting Tomcat.  I am able to manually open it, but that isn't making Tomcat listen to that port.

I don't believe it's a firewall blocking it because I've checked firewall using

```
# firewall-cmd --list-ports
FirewallD is not running
```

I created a Keystore and added it to the Tomcat conf/server.xml since it has an SSL certificate.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/usr/local/mykeystore.keystore" keystorePass="keystorepass"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslVerifyClient="optional"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv2Hello"/>
```

Since I'm new to CentOS and configuring Tomcat like this, I may have made mistakes during the intial install and configuration.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions to help me get this working, or how I should go about reinstalling Tomcat / Java if that's the best option.

Thanks

Comment: (I think this question is more suited for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)) Did you check with `netstat -tlnp`? If the port does not appear as opened look into Tomcat's logs (`catalina.<date>.log`) for messages about connectors. BTW there is a syntax error in your XML `port:"8443"` instead of `port="8443"`.

Comment: Awesome, loading Tomcat now opens port 8080.  I had misread an l as a 1 in the terminal so the JRE_HOME variable was pointing to an invalid directory.

Thanks for your advice about ServerFault and checking Tomcat logs.  I'll keep the ServerFault tag in mind if I have further questions which fit into that category.  Going through the logs was helpful for me to end up figuring out what the problem was.  Also, I corrected my port 8443 entry as well.

Tomcat still isn't working like it should, but at least now I can move forward.  Again, thanks for your help!